# Standard Report Functionality - Are there Wildcard / Joker / Asterisk Characters?

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, filters

Looking at https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YvuGAAS it seem, Salesforce has no * or % support at the standard reports.

Is that true?

Any workarounds without writing some APEX/Visualforce for this?

(I know that there is starts with, ends with - I am looking for real wildcards here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regex function in a formula field and filter your report off of that.

If you have lots of complex filtering like that it can get somewhat unmaintainable but if you just need this for a few fields the formula approach will work well.